# Who are the members of an early design of Luffy's crew?

Tags: one-piece

Browsing through One Piece wiki, there's a databook series called [One Piece Green: Secret Pieces](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/One_Piece_Green:_Secret_Pieces). I found a picture of Mugiwara Pirates early design. This is the picture.

[image]

I can see Zorro, Luffy, Nami, Sanji, and maybe Usopp, Brook, and Chopper. But who is the other two on the left? Did Robin and Franky replace them? Is there any official information about this picture?

Comment: there seems to be something written next to the characters.. someone familiar to the language could help out. Most probably that is the name of each of those characters. :)

Comment: I'm more interested in the drawing on the bottom left; who are they?

Comment: I have no good references but:

The mini character was supposed to be the shipwright and was replaced by Franky.

The other one was meant to be a plant obsessed character who was replaced by Robin and largely incorporated into the post time skip Ussop.

Comment: I haven't watched One piece yet and I don't think I ever will coz of the sheer number of episodes, but could please someone who knows the show's characters post their names in order from left to right on the pic?

Comment: The far left one is label "Shipbuilder," which would become Frankie. The second one from the left is labeled ("Plant/vegetation [something]). It seem all but those two characters were named (see bottom left box for the later concept). Only the shipwright and the herb guy were left unnamed as far as I can tell. It's possible that Usopp's current role mixes the herb guy and his current character role.

Comment: @Krazer you could state this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have no good references but:

The mini character was supposed to be the shipwright and was replaced by Franky.

The other one was meant to be a plant obsessed character who was replaced by Robin and largely incorporated into the post time skip Ussop.